# When checking whether !== undefined, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyName' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

I have encountered this issue several times already. Sometimes it even does nothing, while sometimes it reports this error, seemingly under the same conditions.
I want to check IF something isn't undefined and in such case I want to perform an action. But when it indeed is undefined, I am SOMETIMES getting an error report that it can't be read, because the property is undefined. I would like to understand the principle of this error that seems to appear under certain conditions. Thank you.
The code is for example as follows (part of a loop):

```
    if (objectName[varName].enemy !== undefined)
    {
        console.log("enemy found")
    }
```

Comment: `objectName[varName]` is undefined, so you can't get `undefined.enemy`.

Comment: ```if (varName && objectName[varName] && objectName[varName].enemy !== undefined)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `objectName` or `varName` could be undefined, add checks for those too

Comment: Hi, if I console log the value of a property that is present in every objectName[varName], then there is no issue. (for example objectName[varName].description)

If objectName or varName were undefined, then wouldn't the if condition be simply unfulfilled and thus skipped?

Or is the problem such, that if the "enemy" property isn't present in the particular objectName[varName], then because objectName[varName] is [object Object], it is considered undefined and then the browser reports that it can't check for it's property?

Comment: Yeah that's right!
It doesn't skip if something is undefined, it errors, as you are seeing.
You need to first check that the outer object is not undefined, before going deeper.